# Regex like telephone number on Hive without prefix (+01)

Tags: sql, regex, hive, numbers, rlike

We have a problem with a regular expression on hive.
We need to exclude the numbers with `+37` or `0037` at the beginning of the record (it could be a false result on the regex like) and without letters or space.

We're trying with this one:
`regexp_like(tel_number,'^\+37|^0037+[a-zA-ZÀÈÌÒÙ ]')`
but it doesn't work.

Edit: we want it to come out from the select as true (correct number) or false.

Comment: Are you sure you want to exclude numbers beginning with `+01` or do you mean `+1`?

Comment: Just to be sure: You want to exclude "numbers" **without** letters or space? Or you want to exclude numbers that contain a letter or space?

Comment: sorry, we meant +37 or 0037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude numbers which start with +01 0r +001 or +0001 and having only digits without spaces or letters:

```
... WHERE tel_number NOT rlike '^\\+0{1,3}1\\d+$'
```

Special characters like `+` and character classes like `\d` in Hive should be escaped using double-slash: `\\+` and `\\d`.

Comment: sorry, I meant in the select (I want to see true if the number is ok, false if it isn't)

Comment: @wmbff `select tel_number NOT rlike '^\\+0{1,3}1\\d+$'  as your_col_name ...` - this will give True if number is OK and False if not

Comment: Note that this won't exclude numbers that start with `+01` if they are malformed in any other way like: `+01foo1234`.

Answer (score 1):

The general question is, if you want to describe a malformed telephone number in your regex and *exclude* everything that matches the pattern or if you want to describe a well-formed telephone number and *include* everything that matches the pattern.

Which way to go, depends on your scenario. From what I understand of your requirements, adding "not starting with `0037` or `+37`" as a condition to a well-formed telephone number could be a good approach.

The pattern would be like this:

1. Your number can start with either `+` or `00`: `^(\+|00)`
2. It cannot be followed by a 37 which in regex can be expressed by the following set of alternatives:

   a. It is followed first by a 3 then by anything but 7: `3[0-689]`

   b. It is followed first by anything but 3 then by any number: `[0-24-9]\d`
3. After that there is a sequence of numbers of undefined length (at least one) until the end of the string: `\d+$`

Putting everything together:

```
^(\+|00)(3[0-689]|[0-24-9]\d)\d+$
```

You can play with this regex here and see if this fits your needs: https://regex101.com/r/KK5rjE/3

**Note**: as [leftjoin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2700344/leftjoin) has pointed out: To use this regex in hive you might need to additionally escape the backslashes `\` in the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
regexp_like(tel_number,'^(?!\\+37|0037)\\+?\\d+$')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZPifJ2/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\+37|0037)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `+37` or `0037` immediately to the right of the current location
- `\+?` - an optional `+` sign
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.